# using sendmessage to send wm_close to another process

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, messaging

I want to send wm_close to another process, with which i want end that process safely.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    DWORD SetOfPID;
    SetOfPID = GetProcId(_T("abc.exe"));  //this will return pid
    HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false, SetOfPID);

    HWND hwnd = ::GetTopWindow(NULL);
    while(hwnd)
    {
        DWORD pid;
        DWORD dwThreadId = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
         if(pid == SetOfPID)
         {    
              break;
         }
         hwnd = ::GetNextWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }
    //DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    bool temp = IsWindow(hwnd); **//this gives true**
    LRESULT res = ::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, NULL, NULL);
    DWORD err = GetLastError(); **//this gives 6**
    CloseHandle(hwnd);
    CloseHandle(h);
    return 0;
}
```

this piece of code looks good, but the target process doesn't terminate, can somebody help me?

Comment: Why are you opening the process? That seems unnecessary. Error 6 means an invalid handle. You shouldn't call CloseHandle on a window handle. You don't need to tidy up the window handle, it's not a HANDLE.

Comment: i was trying something else, so opening process is part of that. And i know error 6. 
You shouldn't call CloseHandle on a window handle --> thanks alot for this.

Comment: Sending the WM_CLOSE message to the main form of an app does result in it closing, if that window responds to WM_CLOSE. I can't imagine what you are doing wrong. My recommendation is to use Spy++ to check that you have located the right window handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the window you are finding is the correct one? You can check easily with Spy++. Moreover, when searching for a window, I think it's better to use EnumWindows. I'm not sure your method is correct.

Comment: IsWindow() returns true, doesn't it mean i've a valid window?

Comment: @rplusg: IsWindow tells you it is a valid window handle, not more. It can be that the application has got several top level windows, maybe not visible. And you may not close the right one.

Comment: even i'm not sure what is the problem, but enumwindows has given my desired results. Thanks patriiice, marking your answer as final.

Answer (score 3):

I would attempt to close a (Process with) Window(s) in the following order:

> 1. WM_CLOSE
> 2. WM_QUIT
> 3. WM_DESTROY
> 4. TerminateProcess().

Just my take as I am handling (disabling) `WM_CLOSE` for a Window and having difficulty distinguishing between User Close and close messages send by another master task. `WM_QUIT` seems to resolve my problem without using a custom `WM_APP_CLOSE` of my own. `TerminateProcess` is very much a last resort unclean exit to be avoided at all costs (it may leave handles (e.g. COM etc) and memory etc unfreed).

Answer (score 0):

If the application does not process WM_CLOSE the DefWindowProc should handle this (by gracefully closing the application), however if the application is handling WM_CLOSE then it simply can choose to ignore it. Try sending the WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY messagees instead.

Comment: WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY also doesn't work. DestroyWindow() also returns false.

Comment: WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY can't work, they are notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example of sending messages to a different processes window from [Tonto](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/70669-sending-message-parent-child-process.html) that uses a different method of finding the window to send to.

It uses [EnumWindows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) to walk over the windows.  When it finds the one with the matching PID it sends the message.

Here is a slightly modified version (the same but sends a sends the WM_CLOSE):

```
#include <windows.h>
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD processId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processId);

    if(lParam == processId)
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO         siInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piInfo;
 
    ZeroMemory(&siInfo, sizeof(siInfo));
    ZeroMemory(&piInfo, sizeof(piInfo));
 
    CreateProcess
        ("C:\\WINDOWS\\Notepad.exe", "", 0, 0, 
        FALSE, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, 0, 0, 
        &siInfo, &piInfo);
 
    WaitForSingleObject(piInfo.hProcess, 1000);
    EnumWindows(&EnumWindowsProc, piInfo.dwProcessId);
    return 0;
}
```

This starts C:\WINDOWS\Notepad.exe waits a second and then sends the WM_CLOSE.

This opened notepad and then closed it.  When I tried it with my program instead it also worked, so I think you are having problems find the right window to send the message to.

**NOTE** that there is no error checking in this example.