# How to close Error MessageBox generated at the start up of the device from other application using c++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, pocketpc, shell32

I have my application say `test.exe` which starts whenever i boot my mobile device.

I also kept `dummy.log` file at `MyDevice\Windows\startup\` folder so whenevr i restart my device i see that error message box appears for `dummy.log` file.

I observed in the task manager that `shell32` size gets increase whenever i boot my device with the above configuration.

And also observe that the shell32 size gets increase due to `test.exe` and whenever there is an error messagebox after booting the device.

If i close the error message box then `shell32` size gets decreasing and `test.exe` doesnot create any problem.

Only `Shell32` size gets increase in the above circumstances, in other cases it works fine.

I don't know how the `error message box` is linked with my `test.exe` application.

I debugged and checked and only option i get in my mind is to close the error message box from my application `i.e. test.exe`.

***Edited Section:-***

***Could anyone let me know how to check & close the error message box from  my application i.e. "test.exe"?***

***2nd time editing:-***

***Please also let me know how the error message box could be linked with my application i.e. "test.exe"? Is it anything related to timer? I am not doing anything for the outside windows in my application***

Please reply thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API and then send a [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

for more information read this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402158/using-sendmessage-to-send-wm-close-to-another-process)

Comment: This is working fine. Please let me know how to search *.log file from my app where *.log could be any file which is present at the windows\startup folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the handler to the proccess using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c).
2. Send a mouse event /keystroke to the relvet area using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx)
3. Make the program to run on start-up using [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html)

*You can see where to send the message on the screen by using [spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242713%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) which is usually  included in visual studio.*